# How to share variables in php functions

Tags: php, function, class, variables

Let's say I have two different functions, and one of them has a defined variable. In the second function, I don't wanna write the same variable again, can I simply use the variable from the first function in the second one WITHOUT redefining it in the second function?

Someting like:

```
class example{

    public function a($foo){
        $foo2 = $foo + 1
        return $foo2;
    }

    public function b($foo2){
        echo "result: " . $foo2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a property.

Comment: No i can't. Because in the function "a" i make a specific variable.

Comment: You want to "share" `$foo2` after calling `a()` right?

Comment: Yeah! and use them in `b()`

Comment: Well as as I said, use a property. Check my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, you can use a property `$foo2` and access it from both methods:

```
class example{

    private $foo2;

    public function a($foo){
        $this->foo2 = $foo + 1
        return $this->foo2;
    }

    public function b(){
        echo "result: " . $this->foo2;
    }
}

$obj = new example();

$obj->a(5);
$obj->b(); // result: 6
```

Comment: Why public `$foo2`?

Comment: @James It's just an example I know I should set them to private. I'll update it.

Comment: Nah I get it's a quick example, but they're obviously learning so they'd pick up that as a bad habit ;)

Comment: @James Yes you are right, I should encourage good habits.